# How can one cache bust files referenced in a LESS file when using Symfony2, Twig, and Assetic?

Tags: symfony, caching, less, twig, assetic

I have a web site built on Symfony2 which uses twig templates, LESS, and assetic.

In order to cache bust assets, I'm simply using this in my config.yml:

```
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        assets_version: 'asset-version-here'
```

And then I use the `asset()` function to load the asset and the cache busting is handled for me.

However, the concern I have is when I load my LESS (css) file, there are references to other files, and I would like to know how these files can be cache busted as well.

Example:

```
.someSelector { background:url('../images/filename.png'); }
```

How can I make sure that the referenced file, filename.png is cache busted upon deployment?

The asset files referenced in Twig using asset() are cache busted automatically upon deployment (I use a deployment script hook that updates the assets_version in the framework's config), but those referenced in a stylesheet are not.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to find a natural solution to this issue. In the end because I needed to move forward, I just added a certain tag in the query string, e.g. {ASSETS_VERSION}, and then I search/replace this with the revision number of the project at deployment time as part of my deployment script.

I'm not proud of this solution but it did solve my problem in the short term until I can find a more elegant solution.